# how to apply vue2-perfect-scrollbar or VueScroll js gobally on nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, scrollbar

how can i make all scrollbars in my nuxt project like this one  [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/wn7q7o9ww7?file=/src/main.js)

i actually tried installing and importing this two plugins but nothing has changed in my project.

`vue2-perfect-scrollbar` or `VueScroll js`

i have installed each like this:

```
npm install vue2-perfect-scrollbar
```

and imported it in my plugins folder:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import PerfectScrollbar from 'vue2-perfect-scrollbar'
import 'vue2-perfect-scrollbar/dist/vue2-perfect-scrollbar.css'

 Vue.use(PerfectScrollbar)
```

installing `scrollbar js`:

```
 npm i vuescroll -S
```

importing in plugins:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuescroll from 'vuescroll/dist/vuescroll-native';

Vue.use(vuescroll);
```

`nuxt.config.js`:

```
      plugins: [
        { src: './plugins/vue-scrollbar.js', mode: 'client' },
     ]
```